# storage of data in memory

Tags: memory

i want to know, how will the data be stored in memory ; or what will be the affect of the following code

DATA1 DB 1,2,3

how does my data get stored.. 
if i am using a 80386 or above intel microprocessor..
i am a new with these stuff so kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `db` defines a sequence of bytes so you'll get the three bytes 1, 2 and 3 in increasing memory locations, starting at `data1`.

If `data1` were at 0x00001234, the two statements `db 1,2,3` and `db 3,2,1` (that's one *or* the other, not one *followed* by the other) would give:

```
           DB 1,2,3          DB 3,2,1
           +------+          +------+
0x00001234 | 0x01 |          | 0x03 |
           +------+          +------+
0x00001235 | 0x02 |          | 0x02 |
           +------+          +------+
0x00001236 | 0x03 |          | 0x01 |
           +------+          +------+
```

For example, check out this `debug` session:

```
c:\src> debug

-a 100
1388:0100 db 1,2,3,4
1388:0104 db 9,8,7,6
1388:0108

-d 100 10f
1388:0100  01 02 03 04 09 08 07 06-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................

-q

c:\src> _
```

You can see that the `1`, `2`, `3` and `4` (in that order) go into memory locations `0x0100` through `0x0103` and the `9`, `8`, `7` and `6` (again, in the specified order) go into memory locations `0x0104` through `0x0107`.

Comment: that is one,two and three would be saved in the increasing order??

Comment: Yes, in consecutive memory locations in ascending order. Then the next "statement" would happen at `0x00001237`. See the update.

Comment: @Karan - Yes, since you list them in increasing order.

Comment: since i listed them in increasing order..??  
does this imply that
DATA1 db 3,2,1
would have stored the same data in the same order 1,2,3 or the order wud have been 3,2,1??

Comment: @Karan, `db 3,2,1` would have stored them in the opposite order, 3 then 2 then 1. It's exactly equivalent to the three separate statements `db 3`, `db 2`, `db 1`.